# SFML loadFromFile undefined reference(test works, but crash when add an image)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Before I opened this thread I did a search to prevent duplicate questions, and I found some similar issues, but they are a little old.

I configured the SFML as the official guide suggest(Code Blocks), and I even compiled the test code and actually works, but when I tried to use a texture or image it didn't work. I´ll be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

current SFML version and compiler TDM 4.9.2 and SFML 2.4.0

[image: Image with the error on link]

toolchain executables config

Project config general

config Debug and release

Test project without add images(working)

Comment: One thing that I see is that you are using the static release libraries but the dynamic ones for the debug build. Have you tried putting the necessary .dlls in the folder to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Yes, I already have dlls files in the folder

Comment: Solved, Thanks for your help, I delete all and re-install everyting and works.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use -s in Release Linker

```
sfml-graphics
sfml-audio
sfml-network
sfml-window
sfml-system
```

I think it can help you

Comment: You saved me a lot of hours!! I would give you all of my points if I could!! I used libraries without the "-s" and it worked!! I used "-d" for debug though.